# How to convert a datetime from character String VB

Tags: vb.net, string, date, datetime, converters

Does anyone know how I could convert the following string to a DateTime value in VB ?
How can I convert a character string to datetime? 
My code is provided below would really appreciate some help.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    conn.Open()

    Dim combo1 As Integer
    combo1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    combo1 = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    asd = New SqlCommand("select jam from jadwal where waktu_booking = '" & combo1 & "'", conn)
    TextBox7.Text = asd.ExecuteScalar()
    adm = New SqlCommand("select tarif from tarif_sewa where kode_tarif = '" & TextBox7.Text & "'", conn)
    TextBox2.Text = adm.ExecuteScalar()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

i got an errmsg "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string." on         `TextBox7.Text = asd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact`, `DateTime.TryParseExact` etc to convert the data to a `DateTime` - but then *don't* embed the value in SQL like this. Use parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

use date.tryparse.
e.g.)

```
Dim datstring As String = "2008-01-21 09:10:01"
Dim dateValue As Date
If Date.TryParse(DateString, dateValue) Then
    MsgBox(dateValue)
End If
```